# Alternatives to cartesian in Spark?

Tags: python, mapreduce, apache-spark, combinations, pyspark

I have a RDD of this type:

```
[(1, [3, 10, 11]), (2, [3, 4, 10, 11]), (3, [1, 4]), (4, [2, 3, 10])...]
```

And I need a function that follows this rule:

**if the key `x` does not contain the key `y` (and vice versa) in its value-list**, then outputs a tuple having the following syntax:

```
[(x, [y, len(values_x ^ values_y)]), ...]
```

where `len(values_x ^ values_y)` is the number of values in common between the two keys. If this value is `0` (i.e., no values in common), just skip this pair of keys.

E.g., from the sample above, the output should be:

```
(1, [2, 3]) # because keys 1 and 2 share the values 3, 10, 11
(1, [4, 2]) # because keys 1 and 4 share the values 3, 10
skipping: (2, [1, 3]) is the inverse of (1, [2, 3]), so it can be skipped
(2, [3, 1]) # because keys 2 and 3 share the value 4
...
```

The pair of keys `1` and `3` (and other similar cases) is skipped because key `3` is included in the list-value of key `1` and vice versa.

A solution that I've implemented (but I don't like at all), is using the `cartesian` function to create all the combinations between keys and then a mapping and a filtering to delete unnecessary pairs.

Is there a better solution without using `cartesian`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First lets define some helpers:

```
def swap(x):
    """Given a tuple (x1, x2) return (x2, 1)"""
    return (x[1], 1)

def filter_source(x):
    """Check if s1 < s2 in (x, (s1, s2))"""
    return x[1][0] < x[1][1]

def reshape(kv):
    """Reshape ((k1, k2), v) to get final result"""
    ((k1, k2), v) = kv
    return (k1, (k2, v))
```

and create an example RDD:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([
    (1, [3, 10, 11]), (2, [3, 4, 10, 11]),
    (3, [1, 4]), (4, [2, 3, 10])])
```

Finally you can do something like this:

```
from operator import add

flattened = rdd.flatMap(lambda kv: ((v, kv[0]) for v in kv[1])) # Flatten input
flattened.first()
# (1, 3) <- from (3, [1, 4])

result = (flattened 
    .join(flattened) # Perform self join using value from input as key
    .filter(filter_source) # Remove pairs from the same source
    .map(swap)
    .reduceByKey(add)
    .map(reshape)) # Get final output
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I'm wondering if that ``groupByKey()`` operation could be changed with a ``reduceByKey()`` operation... What do you think about that?

Comment: You're right. I don't know why I had an idea that values are important :) Updated.